# How to wait until random text is displayed in an element

Tags: c#, selenium

In Selenium `C#`, If we want to `wait` until text is displayed in an element then we use below line of code,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Timespan.FromSeconds(10));

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(element, "expected text"));
```

But in my case, the expected text is random and it changes every time, so I want to `wait` until this random text is displayed in an element.

Comment: Could you explain better your scenario?

Comment: Hi  ggeorge, There is an element that displays some text. Everytime it displays different text and this element takes some time to display the text, so I want to wait until this random text is displayed in an element.

Comment: So you want to catch if some text is presented in the element, or you mean the exact random text?

Comment: @Aarif a common problem with stackoverflow questions is the XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - you might be subject to it here. 

I assume you might be using autofixture or similar - you should probably take the input value in an outer scope and check for the actual value. But without more code that is quite difficult to see. Why is the text random?

Answer (score 1):

As the value could be randomly generated (unless there is a pattern to the randomness), you'll find it difficult to find the value by text. If there is a pattern, you could use a regular expression match to find the value but this could match on other UI elements which might not be expected.

You could find the element by providing an ID on the element that contains the text. Then you could simply wait until that element is visible with:

```cs
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(driver => driver.FindElementById("your-id").Displayed);
```

If the text is empty and then populated, and you want to wait until the text is populated, you could also check that the text value is not null or empty:

```cs
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(driver => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(driver.FindElementById("your-id").Text));
```